# Evidence about the group $\left ( (\mathbb{Z}/p\mathbb{Z})^*,\underset{p}{ \odot} \right )$

Tags: group-theory, finite-groups, order-theory, abelian-groups

> Be $p$ an odd prime number. Show that the group $\left ( (\mathbb{Z}/p\mathbb{Z})^*,\underset{p}{ \odot} \right )$ has a unique element of order $2$, namely $\overline{p-1}$, and show that $(p-1)!\equiv p-1 \pmod{p}$ (Wilson's Theorem)

The first part, I managed to do.

$$\overline{(p-1)}\underset{p}{\odot}\overline{(p-1)}=\overline{p^2}-\overline{2p}+\overline{1}=\overline1$$Because $p\mid p^2-2p$, then $\overline{p-1}$  has order $2$.

To prove that it is unique. And Wilson's theorem, how do?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

**I will use a lighter notation**

If $x$ has the order $2$ then
$$x^2=1\iff (x-1)(x+1)=0$$
but since $x\ne1$ and $\Bbb Z/p\Bbb Z$ is a field since $p$ is prime then we have
$$x+1=0\iff x=-1$$
hence $-1=p-1$ is the only element equal to his inverse *(except also $1$)*.

Now we have
$$(p-1)!=1\times \underbrace{2\times\cdots (p-2)}_{=1}\times(p-1)$$
since every element from $2$ to $p-2$ has his inverse in this set which's different to this element hence
$$(p-1)!=p-1$$

Comment: $2$ for $p-2$ we have that each element has its inverse, but this needs to be Abelian, right? This group is abelian?

Comment: Yes it's  abelian. To be more scientist notice that I already said in my answer that $\Bbb Z/p\Bbb Z$ is a field and it's finite. Do you know a theorem that affirm that every finite field is commutative:  *wedderburn theorem*?

Comment: No, unfortunately I do not know the theorem.

Comment: There's no problem since **fortunately** the commutativity in our case is trivial:-)